# Component Application Block for .NET 2.0 (WinForms) - What are the new versions?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, cab

What are the new versions of CAB, mainly for WPF? What is changed? Is it the same stuff, adjusted for WPF characteristics? Does it still rely on Unity (and SCSF for the matter)?

I find Microsoft and MSDN to be very confusing sometimes ... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WPF version of CAB is [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).

It's changed... quite a bit, although supposedly you *can* get CAB projects up and running in Prism with a bit of work.  I don't think there's any one definitive document on the subject, but you can find a lot of information about the differences in this [migration guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/mszcool/archive/2008/07/11/migrate-from-cab-scsf-to-composite-wpf-guidance-prism.aspx) (Winforms CAB to Prism).

SCSF is completely gone, although there are replacements [in development](http://scsfwpf.codeplex.com/).  Unity is still used, but has of course been updated as well.

Comment: That migration guide helped, a lot (!) ... I've heard about Prism, but when you are confused, that is when you need a little clarification :) Thanks a lot !